# Anistropic points clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan, gmm

The K-means method cannot deal with anistropic points. The DBSCAN and Gaussian Mixture model seems that they can work with this according to scikit-learn. I have tried to use both approaches, but they are not working for my [dataset](https://pastebin.com/m7uNAbE2).

DBSCAN

I used the following code:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.1,min_samples=5 ).fit(X_train,Y_train)
labels_train=db.labels_
# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels_train)) - (1 if -1 in labels_train else 0)
print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
```

and only 1 cluster (Estimated number of clusters: 1) was detected as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzN2G.png).

Gaussian Mixture model

The code was as follows:

```
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(X_train,Y_train)
labels_train=gmm.predict(X_train)
print(gmm.bic(X_train))
```

The two clusters could not be distinguished as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHeWc.png).

How can i detect two clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation.

> fit(X, y=None, sample_weight=None)
>
> X : array or sparse (CSR) **matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features)** [...]
>
> ...
>
> y : Ignored

So your invocation ignores the y coordinate.

Don't we all love python/sklearn, because it doesn't even warn you of this, but silently ignores `y`?

`X` should be the entire data, not just the x coordinates.

The notion of "train" and "predict" does not make sense for clustering. Don't use it. Only use `fit_predict`.